# How does Outlook 2007 decide if it should redirect an e-mail to the Junk E-mail folder?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, spam, spam-prevention

My Question:

> How does Outlook 2007 decide if it
>   should redirect an e-mail to the Junk
>   E-mail folder?

Background Story:
When I send a simple HTML e-mail from my domain mailbox, it's being redirected to the Junk E-mail folder.

Here are two sub questions:

1. Does Outlook 2007 care if the sender's outbound mailbox's reverse PTR is incorrectly configured? [If so, how can it check?]
2. Does Outlook 2007 care if the sender doesn't provide a plain text version of the HTML content?

**EDIT:** It turns out, I'm not the only one wondering about Outlook's junk algorithm. See the comments attached to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642211/outlook-marking-email-as-junk-email/2642251#2642251).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [helpful answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/84469/is-there-any-way-to-see-why-outlooks-client-junk-mail-filter-is-marking-a-messag/84509#84509).

> "...The technology used for message
>   content analysis is also far from
>   being perfect. Microsoft has created a
>   dictionary of several tens thousand
>   words, and assigned different weights
>   to the words in the dictionary. The
>   message content analysis is nothing
>   more than mere summation of weights of
>   words contained in the message."

And here's [another one](http://www.being-smarter.com/2010/05/how-to-avoid-the-outlook-junk-filter/).

---

But bear in mind:

- Microsoft intentionally keeps
  Outlook's spam filtering rules
  **secret**.
- Because if they didn't, spammers would have a playbook for
  which they could circumvent the
  rules.