# Microsoft outlook and PHP email fail to be a valid email it goes straight to the junk box if i change email contents to hello world works. rubish err

Tags: php, zend-framework, pear

**Nightmare Episode 1**

I put 21 hours today to solve this. But i failed, asking experts to have a look, checked almost **PEAR** all possibilities but this Microsoft Outlook never gives up. What is this secret ?

**Microsoft Outlook 2010** as receives as **junk email** when i put junk filter to "High". If i send another email with my same account from Google it goes to Inbox. 
What is the problem with this Outlook ? I tried to follow multipart/alternative or multipart/mixed or multipart/relative but all Same.

My server log shows: 100% ok no spam not blacklist, all clear
Dec  8 15:42:30 www postfix/smtp[15250]: C99908162: to=, relay=mail.andmylab.com[01.01.01.01]:25, delay=0.25, delays=0.07/0.01/0.08/0.09, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1PQQqL-0001b6-TA)

My blacklist: www.whatismyipaddress.com shows no black list all green
- I can send to Google or to my own domain and other domain without any problems.

My code: its generating exactly multipart/alternative where i am following RFC standards

```
  /* DB details */
  $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/cloude.ini', 'production');
  define("DBHOST",     $config->resources->db->params->host);
  define("DBUSER",     $config->resources->db->params->username);
  define("DBPASS",     $config->resources->db->params->password);
  define("DEFAULT_DB", $config->resources->db->params->dbname);
  define("MAILER_TABLE", "mail_queue");


  /* 1 --------------------- PEAR!! */
  require_once "Mail/Queue.php";
  require_once 'Mail/mime.php';
  require_once 'Mail/mimePart.php';

  /* 2 --------------------- DB */
  $db_options['type']       = 'db';
  $db_options['dsn']        = 'mysql://' . DBUSER . ":" . DBPASS . "@" . DBHOST . "/" . DEFAULT_DB;
  $db_options['mail_table'] = MAILER_TABLE;
  $mail_options['driver']   = 'mail';

  /* Step ------------------ 1 */
  $mail_queue =& new Mail_Queue($db_options, $mail_options);
  $from = "validguy@lul.be";

  /* Step ------------------ 2 */
  $mime =& new Mail_mime($crlf = "\n");
  $mail =& Mail::factory($mail_options['driver']); 

  /* Step ------------------ 3 Plain text and Html  */
  $data->mode = 'html';

  if ($data->mode=='html') 
  { 
      /* A <--------------- part */
      $params['content_type'] = 'multipart/alternative';
      $email = new Mail_mimePart('', $params);

      /* B <--------------- part */
      $email = $email->encode();
      $email['headers']['Mime-Version']   = '1.0';
      $email['headers']['Subject']        =  $fix;                
      $email['headers']['From']           =  $from; 

      //Zend_Debug::dump($email);
      // exit;

      /* C <--------------- part */
      $mime->setTXTBody('Test');
      $mime->setHTMLBody($txt2);

      /* D <--------------- part */
      $body = $mime->get();
      $hdrs = $mime->headers($email['headers']);                  


  } else if($data->mode=='both') {

    // later... for multipart/relative

  } else {

    // later... for inline    

  }

  /* Step 4 - done */
  $mailResult = $mail_queue->put($from, $row->email, $hdrs, $body, 0,true,$nres[0]['id']);
  //$mailResult = $mail_queue->put($from, $row->email, $email['headers'], $email['body'], 0,true,$nres[0]['id']);

  if(!PEAR::isError($mailResult)){ $m++; } else {   $n++; }

}

}

/* Relax........ */
echo "Records transfered: " . $m . "<br/>";
echo "Records failed to transfer: " . $n . "<br/>";
```

**Nightmare Episode 1 (FOLLOW UP)**

> SPF fix (zone file setting, required)
>   - Go to all SPF testing sites, and check what there wizard saying
>
> Fix PTR (zone file setting, required)
>
> Dkim proxy (zone file setting, required)
>
> Prepare two version Plain text and Html
>
> Check message headers from working emails that arrives without any problem to your inbox like (Google/Yahoo and others top companies), and compare that towards yours
>
> Do not trust Microsoft Outlook 2010 or Old version, because in junk filter (high) its also written similar, **it may not be a spam** that must be a business issue, to make us stupid. And put us in nightmare to solve those issues.

- If you don't agree in those **TOP reasons**, please advise and bit it, this is what i learned and trying to share, because its very annoying as a developer, if you don't have any answer for this **RUBISH EROR**, caused by Microsoft Outlook 2010.

Comment: haha, 1+ for "rubish err" and a jumbled title.

Comment: If SPF and DKIM won't help, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642211/outlook-marking-email-as-junk-email or consult Microsoft support.

Comment: RFCs have very little to do with the random machinations people use to try to detect spam. Is it really MSOutlook which decides its spam? Or the mailserver? Have a look through the posts here about php and spam for some hints.

Comment: @MARIO, thanks just installed it by searching 100 websites only there was 1 which explained it. How to work it out. After that still it goes to Junk box. Does it makes any sense, what outlook 2010 is upto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all its Microsoft itself. To really overcome with this issue you can take action such as:

1. MailChimp: very nice, after pulling all my hair out why it does not work, i found that they got some nice templates with special secret inside, but any way, i just customized it, and it works,  i can hit straight  crap Outlook express "Inbox" even its high spam filtered.